# Two $t-$Tests for the hypothesis $H_0: \lvert \mu \rvert \ge \epsilon$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, self-study, equivalence

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $X_1,\ldots, X_n \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ with $\sigma^2$ unknown. Show that a level $\alpha$ test for the hypothesis
>
> $$H_0: \lvert \mu \rvert \ge \epsilon \quad \text{ vs. } \quad H_1: \lvert \mu \rvert < \epsilon$$
>
> can be formulated by using two one-sided $t-$tests  of significance level $\alpha$.

I think that the way to solve this is by using the test statistic

$$T := \frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{S^{*}} \cdot \sqrt{n}$$

, which is $t-$distributed with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. ($S^*$ denotes the corrected sample standard deviation.) So we accept if

$$t > t_{n-1;1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$$

or

$$t < t_{n-1;\frac{\alpha}{2}} = -t_{n-1;1-\frac{\alpha}{2}} $$

Could you please tell me whether I am right?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).